# Bitcoin Core 0.13.1 shutdown with I/O device error

Tags: bitcoin-core

I downloaded Bitcoin Core 0.13.1. After starting the program it gives me an error:

> 2016-11-09 18:38:17 IO error:
>   C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\chainstate\304129.ldb: Impossibile
>   eseguire la richiesta a causa di un errore di dispositivo I/O.
>   2016-11-09 18:38:17 *** System error while flushing: Database I/O
>   error

The error seems to translate to English as "Failed to execute request due to a I/O device error."

Comment: I think this error is the equivalent of the english error "[The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/request-could-not-be-performed-io-device-error)."

Answer (score 1):

You may want to [check the state of your disk to make sure there are no issues](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/7248), also, [that your data directory has the correct permissions set](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1362047.0).

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Impossibile eseguire la richiesta a causa di un errore di dispositivo I/O.

Apparently means something along the lines of: 
"The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error."

There is likely an issue with your hard disk. You should create a backup of your `wallet.dat`, then run disk diagnostics, and perhaps replace the disk in the near future if the diagnostics indicate a problem.